# How do I make a new command with author/journal/year citation in footnote

Tags: macros, environments

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}%backend=biber, natbib=true, style=chem-acs
\bibliography{oralspaper}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\citejournal}%%%creating \citejournal command
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{journal}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\newcommand{\scicite}[3]{\citeauthor{#1}, \citejournal{#1}, \citeyear{#1}}

%%%%%%I want to incorporate the \footnote environment into the new command (below) but I get an error

%%%%%%\newcommand{\scicitefoot}[3]{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{\citeauthor{#1}, \citejournal{#1}, \citeyear{#1}}}%\scicite{} is footnote presentation style citation



\begin{document}

\frame{

Some text/figure I want to have a source for.

\footnote{\scicite{bib.citekey}}%this works fine
}

\frame{
\scicitefoot{bib.citekey}%this gives latex error: begin{beamer@framepauses} on input line 5
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that I would like the footnote to not have a number which is why I have the \let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{} instead of just \footnote{}. Thanks for the help and patience I'm a first time poster.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks! I think I may have answered my question. Setting it up iteratively worked for some reason. The second \newcommand must be changed: \newcommand{\scicitefoot}[1]{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{\scicite{#1}}}

Comment: You can provide a self answer in the box below.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments

Comment: Go for it. It is solved.